# Entity Framework 6 with Azure DB secondary connection

Tags: sql, azure, entity-framework-6, geo

I'm facing a problem with EF against Azure DB secondary connection. Here is my problem:

- I'm using EF 6 with code first
- I already setup a primary Azure DB with 2 Active GEO-Replicated secondary database (have difference server and db name as well as login account)
- I use EF6 to manipulate the primary Azure DB. The case is that if the primary DB is down (by any reason) and I want to switch to the active secondary dbs for select statements at runtime. How can I achieved that?

Notes: For example, I have the code snippet below:

```
using (AppContext context = new AppContext()) // AppContext is derived from DbContext and using the primary connection string
{
     var users = await context.Users.ToListAsync(); // If this line of code failed with the primary connection string
}
```

I want to auto-switch dynamically to the secondary db if the line var users... is failed at runtime. Any recommendation?

Thanks for your help!